# On shake... iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, shake, first-responder

So I have an IBAction `yesNo` that I want to be ran on a shake event. Not all too sure why this is not working. Have followed all the documentation.

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {
        [self yesNo];
    }
}
```

And then the IBAction itself:

```
- (IBAction)yesNo 
{
    int rNumber = rand() % 26;  
    NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([[def objectForKey:@"activeVersion"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        switch (rNumber) {
            case 0:
                result.text  = @"Never";
                break;
            case 1:
                result.text = @"If you're lucky...";
                break;
            case 3:
                result.text = @"Think twice";
                break;
            ...
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else if ([[def objectForKey:@"activeVersion"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        switch (rNumber) {
            case 0:
                result.text  = @"Never1";
                break;
            case 1:
                result.text = @"If you're lucky...1";
                break;
            ...
            case 25:
                result.text = @"Very doubtful2";
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else if ([[def objectForKey:@"activeVersion"] isEqualToString:@"3"])
    {
        switch (rNumber) {
        case 0:
            result.text  = @"Never3";
            break;
        ...
        case 25:
            result.text = @"Very doubtful3";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}   
}
```

Basically what I have is a fortune ball type thing and when the iPhone is shaken I need that IBAction run.

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is `yesNo` being called? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Where are you setting the value for key `activeVersion`? It probably is not satisfying any of the conditions. Have you checked whether the method is being called by logging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you made that view the first responder? I.e. `[yourView becomeFirstResponder];` (probably from some `viewDidAppear:` method).
You might want to check if it actually is the first responder when you shake your device.

Answer (score 2):

When I was switching from defining everything graphically in IB to programmatically inline in Xcode, I forgot to make the view the first responder at all. Here's the code that ultimately fixed it:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"self is first responder %i",[self isFirstResponder]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would question is whether this should be defined as an IBAction. If you only call it from code then you might want to consider using (void) instead (Simply a style choice).

Secondly, are you sure that the method is actually being called? Throw an NSLog in there to make sure.

Thirdly, are you sure that [def objectForKey:@"activeVersion"] returns a string? Is the value returned what you would expect? Throw an NSLog in there to make sure.

My guess is that one of the NSLogs will give you the answer to your question as the rest of your code seems fine.

Comment: +1 I am agree with these points specially make it void and use NSLog and debug correctly.

Comment: Yes, the `yesNo` method works. I also have a button so that if the ball area is touched the method is ran. Yes, the `def objectForKey` is returning a string.

Comment: Then you have some more debugging to do. Put is more NSLogs in places where you expect the code to run, or, as Luke says, start using breakpoints. Please don't take this the wrong way, but debugging is a core competency for programming. Learn how to do it and you can spend 5 minutes finding the problem rather than a full day going back and forth on stackoverflow. At the end of the day, either one of your variables is not correct, or your checks (switch statements, if statements, etc) is not returning the result you expect. Apple has given you tools to find things, please use them.